# How can I git push my Flask web app to Heroku?

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, web-applications, push

I'm following Ardit's Pyhton course ==> The Python Mega Course: Build 10 Real World Applications.

I'm at the building a flask web application, and uploading it to Heroku. The lecture is good and I understand everything, but obviously I'm missing something as when I try the final step - git push master, I get the error message that the push failed and the app couldn't be compiled.

I tried to troubleshoot the issue by reading the error message but I'm not yet at a level where I can understand what to do, and I couldn't find any viable solution on the internet, reason why I'm requesting someone's help here (thanks in advance). The full error message can be found below:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Python app detected
-----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
-----> Installing python-3.10.7
-----> Installing pip 22.2.2, setuptools 63.4.3 and wheel 0.37.1
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting addict==2.4.0
         Downloading addict-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.8 kB)
       Collecting aiofiles==0.8.0
         Downloading aiofiles-0.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
       Collecting anyio==3.6.1
         Downloading anyio-3.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (80 kB)
       Collecting appnope==0.1.2
         Downloading appnope-0.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.3 kB)
       Collecting argon2-cffi==21.3.0
         Downloading argon2_cffi-21.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
       Collecting argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
         Downloading argon2_cffi_bindings-21.2.0-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (86 kB)
       Collecting asgiref==3.5.2
         Downloading asgiref-3.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
       Collecting asttokens==2.0.5
         Downloading asttokens-2.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
       Collecting attrs==21.4.0
         Downloading attrs-21.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
       Collecting backcall==0.2.0
         Downloading backcall-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
       Collecting backports.entry-points-selectable==1.1.0
         Downloading backports.entry_points_selectable-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2 kB)
       Collecting black==22.1.0
         Downloading black-22.1.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.5 MB)
       Collecting bleach==4.1.0
         Downloading bleach-4.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (157 kB)
       Collecting branca==0.4.2
         Downloading branca-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
       Collecting certifi==2021.5.30
         Downloading certifi-2021.5.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
       Collecting cffi==1.15.0
         Downloading cffi-1.15.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (446 kB)
       Collecting charset-normalizer==2.0.3
         Downloading charset_normalizer-2.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
       Collecting click==8.0.3
         Downloading click-8.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
       Collecting commonmark==0.9.1
         Downloading commonmark-0.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (51 kB)
       Collecting cycler==0.10.0
         Downloading cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.5 kB)
       Collecting debugpy==1.5.1
         Downloading debugpy-1.5.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.9 MB)
       Collecting decorator==5.1.1
         Downloading decorator-5.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.1 kB)
       Collecting defusedxml==0.7.1
         Downloading defusedxml-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
       Collecting demjson3==3.0.5
         Downloading demjson3-3.0.5.tar.gz (132 kB)
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
       Collecting distlib==0.3.2
         Downloading distlib-0.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (338 kB)
       Collecting docutils==0.18.1
         Downloading docutils-0.18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (570 kB)
       Collecting entrypoints==0.3
         Downloading entrypoints-0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
       Collecting et-xmlfile==1.1.0
         Downloading et_xmlfile-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 kB)
       Collecting executing==0.8.2
         Downloading executing-0.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
       Collecting filelock==3.0.12
         Downloading filelock-3.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
       Collecting Flask==2.1.2
         Downloading Flask-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
       Collecting folium==0.12.1.post1
         Downloading folium-0.12.1.post1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
       Collecting gunicorn==20.1.0
         Downloading gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
       Collecting h11==0.12.0
         Downloading h11-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
       Collecting httpcore==0.15.0
         Downloading httpcore-0.15.0-py3-none-any.whl (68 kB)
       Collecting httpx==0.23.0
         Downloading httpx-0.23.0-py3-none-any.whl (84 kB)
       Collecting idna==3.2
         Downloading idna-3.2-py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
       Collecting importlib-metadata==4.11.4
         Downloading importlib_metadata-4.11.4-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
       Collecting importlib-resources==5.4.0
         Downloading importlib_resources-5.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
       Collecting ipykernel==6.8.0
         Downloading ipykernel-6.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (128 kB)
       Collecting ipython==8.0.1
         Downloading ipython-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (747 kB)
       Collecting ipython-genutils==0.2.0
         Downloading ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
       Collecting ipywidgets==7.6.5
         Downloading ipywidgets-7.6.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
       Collecting itsdangerous==2.1.2
         Downloading itsdangerous-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
       Collecting jedi==0.18.1
         Downloading jedi-0.18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
       Collecting Jinja2==3.0.3
         Downloading Jinja2-3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
       Collecting jsonschema==4.4.0
         Downloading jsonschema-4.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (72 kB)
       Collecting jupyter==1.0.0
         Downloading jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.7 kB)
       Collecting jupyter-client==7.1.2
         Downloading jupyter_client-7.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (130 kB)
       Collecting jupyter-console==6.4.0
         Downloading jupyter_console-6.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
       Collecting jupyter-core==4.9.1
         Downloading jupyter_core-4.9.1-py3-none-any.whl (86 kB)
       Collecting jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2
         Downloading jupyterlab_pygments-0.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.6 kB)
       Collecting jupyterlab-widgets==1.0.2
         Downloading jupyterlab_widgets-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (243 kB)
       Collecting justpy==0.2.3
         Downloading justpy-0.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.5 MB)
       Collecting keyring==23.5.1
         Downloading keyring-23.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
       Collecting kiwisolver==1.3.1
         Downloading kiwisolver-1.3.1.tar.gz (53 kB)
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
       Collecting MarkupSafe==2.0.1
         Downloading MarkupSafe-2.0.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (30 kB)
       Collecting matplotlib==3.4.2
         Downloading matplotlib-3.4.2.tar.gz (37.3 MB)
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
       Collecting matplotlib-inline==0.1.3
         Downloading matplotlib_inline-0.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
       Collecting mistune==0.8.4
         Downloading mistune-0.8.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
       Collecting mypy-extensions==0.4.3
         Downloading mypy_extensions-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.5 kB)
       Collecting mysql-connector-python==8.0.28
         Downloading mysql_connector_python-8.0.28-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (37.6 MB)
       Collecting nbclient==0.5.10
         Downloading nbclient-0.5.10-py3-none-any.whl (69 kB)
       Collecting nbconvert==6.4.1
         Downloading nbconvert-6.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (557 kB)
       Collecting nbformat==5.1.3
         Downloading nbformat-5.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
       Collecting nest-asyncio==1.5.4
         Downloading nest_asyncio-1.5.4-py3-none-any.whl (5.1 kB)
       Collecting notebook==6.4.8
         Downloading notebook-6.4.8-py3-none-any.whl (9.9 MB)
       Collecting numpy==1.21.0
         Downloading numpy-1.21.0.zip (10.3 MB)
         Installing build dependencies: started
         Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
         Getting requirements to build wheel: started
         Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
         Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
         Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
       Collecting opencv-python==4.5.5.62
         Downloading opencv_python-4.5.5.62-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (60.4 MB)
       Collecting openpyxl==3.0.9
         Downloading openpyxl-3.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (242 kB)
       Collecting packaging==21.3
         Downloading packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
       Collecting pandas==1.4.0
         Downloading pandas-1.4.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (11.7 MB)
       Collecting pandocfilters==1.5.0
         Downloading pandocfilters-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.7 kB)
       Collecting parso==0.8.3
         Downloading parso-0.8.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (100 kB)
       Collecting pathspec==0.9.0
         Downloading pathspec-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
       Collecting pexpect==4.8.0
         Downloading pexpect-4.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
       Collecting pickleshare==0.7.5
         Downloading pickleshare-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9 kB)
       Collecting Pillow==8.2.0
         Downloading Pillow-8.2.0.tar.gz (47.9 MB)
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
       Collecting pkginfo==1.8.2
         Downloading pkginfo-1.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
       Collecting platformdirs==2.2.0
         Downloading platformdirs-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
       Collecting prometheus-client==0.13.1
         Downloading prometheus_client-0.13.1-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
       Collecting prompt-toolkit==3.0.26
         Downloading prompt_toolkit-3.0.26-py3-none-any.whl (375 kB)
       Collecting protobuf==3.19.4
         Downloading protobuf-3.19.4-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.1 MB)
       Collecting ptyprocess==0.7.0
         Downloading ptyprocess-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
       Collecting pure-eval==0.2.2
         Downloading pure_eval-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
       Collecting pycparser==2.21
         Downloading pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
       Collecting pygal==2.4.0
         Downloading pygal-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127 kB)
       Collecting pygal-maps-world==1.0.2
         Downloading pygal_maps_world-1.0.2.tar.gz (270 kB)
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
       Collecting pygame==2.0.0.dev6
         Downloading pygame-2.0.0.dev6.tar.gz (3.7 MB)
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
         Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
         error: subprocess-exited-with-error
         
         × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
         │ exit code: 1
         ╰─> [29 lines of output]
             
             
             WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
             Using UNIX configuration...
             
             
             Hunting dependencies...
             /bin/sh: 1: sdl2-config: not found
             /bin/sh: 1: sdl2-config: not found
             /bin/sh: 1: sdl2-config: not found
             WARNING: "sdl2-config" failed!
             
             ---
             For help with compilation see:
                 https://www.pygame.org/wiki/Compilation
             To contribute to pygame development see:
                 https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
             ---
             
             Traceback (most recent call last):
               File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
               File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
               File "/tmp/pip-install-aj1dsspj/pygame_dc91e33a8ee04f5bbdeb369f8983e39c/setup.py", line 258, in <module>
                 buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
               File "/tmp/pip-install-aj1dsspj/pygame_dc91e33a8ee04f5bbdeb369f8983e39c/buildconfig/config.py", line 208, in main
                 deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
               File "/tmp/pip-install-aj1dsspj/pygame_dc91e33a8ee04f5bbdeb369f8983e39c/buildconfig/config_unix.py", line 223, in main
                 raise RuntimeError('Unable to run "sdl-config". Please make sure a development version of SDL is installed.')
             RuntimeError: Unable to run "sdl-config". Please make sure a development version of SDL is installed.
             [end of output]
         
         note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
       error: metadata-generation-failed
       
       × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
       ╰─> See above for output.
       
       note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
       hint: See above for details.
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Why do you have a dependency on Pygame? Heroku doesn't provide a graphical interface.

Comment: @Chris I actually don't know. I previously created a virtual environment in which I installed Flask. Then, back in the webapp directory, I created the requirements.txt in which there should be dependencies listed (from what I understan). I thought the list should only contain what is installed in the virtual environment, but for some reason I don't grasp, pygame (along with many other libraries I didn't pip install in the venv) are listed...

Should I just delete this dependencies from the "requirements.txt" or it is not as easy as that?

Comment: Yes, your `requirements.txt` should only contain dependencies you actually need. Are you generating it by running `pip freeze`? If so, you may be in the wrong environment or your environment may have packages installed that you don't actually need.

Comment: @Chris Yes, in terminal I made sure I pointed to the webapp directory and executed the command line "pip freeze > requirements.txt".

I think it comes from the fact that to install packages in my virtual environment, using Terminal, I go in the directory, using cd ***, where are located the packages (virtual/bin) and  "pip install". Now I noticed that whether I install Flask or Gunicorn using this method, they both don't appear in virtual/bin, meaning they were not installed in my virtual environment, and when I pip freeze > requirements.txt, It gets all the dependencies from my local Python

Comment: @Chris It's a stupid, but I thought I just needed to be in the virtual/bin directory and execute pip install, when obviously it is not the case. In summary:
- How to pip install packages in a virtual environment only (I know the command line "pip install" but how to point to the directory virtual/bin)?
- How to make sure the pip freeze>requirements.txt gets the dependencies only from the packages installed previously in the virtual environment?

Thx

Comment: It's not about where you are, but which Python environment you have enabled. The exact way to proceed depends a bit on how you created and manage your virtual environments, but when you `pip install` something it gets installed into whatever the active environment is. You should make sure to activate the correct environment before installing libraries, or running `pip freeze`. That might mean sourcing a `bin/activate` or `Scripts/activate`, running `workon`, using `pipenv` or `poetry` commands, ...

Comment: Oh ok, then after installing my virtual environment, I must activate it before I pip install any kind of modules in it (such as Flask and Gunicorn)? Thus, first, I install it:

- python3 -m venv virtual

Then I activate it

- bin/activate

Then I may install flask and gunicorn

- pip install flask

- pip install gunicorn

Then I may finally create my requirements with dependencies

- pip freeze>requirements.txt

Is this quite the right order in which to proceed?

Comment: Yep, that looks right! If you exit from the virtual environment (e.g. by running `deactivate` or by closing your terminal) you'll have to re-activate it before adding more dependencies or running `pip freeze`.

Comment: It all worked to deploy the app on Heroku ! Thanks for your help !

Comment: But now, I have another issue:

app[api]: Build succeede
d
heroku[router]: at=error
 code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path
="/" host=testappzxy.herokuapp.com request_id=6252d295-3d
cc-4293-bfc6-884650607ae1 fwd="212.239.228.121" dyno= con
nect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
heroku[router]: at=error
 code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path
="/favicon.ico" host=testappzxy.herokuapp.com request_id=
3f8e480e-4113-4154-a45d-36e94a338703 fwd="212.239.228.121
" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http

Comment: That's a completely different issue, and there are [plenty of existing questions about how to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheroku%5D+no+web+processes+running).

Comment: True, I will have a look, and worst case scenario, open a new issue. Many thanks again for your help. Cheers!